# How to reach chests buried in the ground?

Tags: risk-of-rain

More than once I came across chests buried in the ground.  Is there a way to reach them?

[image: Safe buried in the ground]

Comment: here is an article on the on the wiki:

http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Sunken_Tomb

Comment: Perhaps I missed something but I think this wiki page doesn't explain how to get to the chest.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get that chest by falling down into the pit to the left of it, which then teleported me up where the chest is. There's some area over to the left you have to get to first, but don't be afraid of falling/drowning, it won't do anything to you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer !  Once you've reached the chest, how did you manage to get out of there ?  I didn't exactly get the thing about the area on the left; could you provide a few more details?

Comment: I think you can go though the wall if you have the Mercenary and enough move speed.its also a lot easier if you have a lot of photon. watch this and skip to 49:22: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGRoWM1XSSk

Comment: I fell down and accidentally got respawned inside wall above and couldn't get out. So if you really want to get that chest, beware you could get stuck.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and just got respawned at the top, where I first spawned in